# Update or add value to aggregate in data.frame

Tags: r, cumsum

Let's say I have the following simple `data.frame`:

```
    ID  value
1    1    3
2    2    4
3    1    5
4    3    3
```

My desired output is below, where we add a `value` to `cumsum` or we update it according to the latest `value` of an already used `ID`.

```
    ID  value  cumsum
1    1    3       3
2    2    4       7
3    1    5       9
4    3    3       12
```

In row 3, the new `value` forms an updated `cumsum` `(7-3+5=9)`. Row 4 adds a new `value` to `cumsum` because the `ID` was not used before `(4+5+3=12)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `data.table` for `cumsum`. Calculating the cumulative mean is a bit more tricky because the number of oberservations is not adjusted by just using `cummean`.

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(id = c(1, 2, 1, 3), value = c(3, 4, 5, 3))

dt[, tmp := value-shift(value, n = 1L, type = "lag", fill = 0), by = c("id")]

#CUMSUM
dt[, cumsum := cumsum(tmp)]

#CUMMEAN WITH UPDATED N
dt[value != tmp, skip := 1:.N]
dt[, skip := na.locf(skip, na.rm = FALSE)]
dt[is.na(skip), skip := 0]
dt[, cummean := cumsum(tmp)/(seq_along(tmp)-skip)]
```

Output is:

```
       id value tmp cumsum skip cummean
   1:  1     3   3      3    0     3.0
   2:  2     4   4      7    0     3.5
   3:  1     5   2      9    1     4.5
   4:  3     3   3     12    1     4.0
```

Edit: Changed `lag` function to `data.table`'s `shift` function.

Answer (score 1):

This produces the desired outcome for your example:

```
df<-read.table(header=T, text="ID  value
1    1    3
2    2    4
3    1    5
4    3    3")
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(value = value-lag(value, def = 0L)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% mutate(cumsum = cumsum(value)) 
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#      ID value cumsum
#   <int> <int>  <int>
# 1     1     3      3
# 2     2     4      7
# 3     1     2      9
# 4     3     3     12
```

Comment: That works fine, thanks! Is there a way to make it work with `cummean` too? It seems that n is not updated.

Comment: @Stefan Can you add an example inlcuding input, code and expected output?